Maximal intransitive subgroups are maximal subgroups of $S_n$
Let $K$ be a maximal intransitive subgroup of $S_n$, i.e. maximal among the intransitive subgroups. I proved that $K$ is of the form
$$K=Stab(O)=\{g \in S_n \mid Og=O\},$$
where $O$ is a proper non-empty subset of $\Omega=\{1,\dots,n\}$.
Now, I want to prove that $K$ is indeed a maximal subgroup of $S_n$, unless $|O|=|\Omega \setminus O|$.
To do this, I am assuming that $K$ is not maximal in $S_n$. Then, $K$ is properly contained in some subgroup $M$, which is therefore transitive.
First of all, I assume that $M$ is primitive.
The notes that I am following now say that:
since $M$ is primitive, it contains a 2-cycle, moving two elements of $O$ or of $\Omega \setminus O$.
This point is unclear to me, I don't understand why $M$ should contain this two 2-cycle.
(I want to use the fact that $M$ contains a transposition because a corollary of Jordan's theorem says that a primitive permutation group containing a transposition must be equal to $S_n$.)
My idea is that $Stab(O)$ contains a transposition, that moves two elements of $O$ and fixes all other elements, but this idea seems different to what the notes seem to say. So, what is the right way to see that $M$ contains a 2-cycle? Any hint is much appreciated.

Yes, thank you! That was the idea that I had in mind, but I didn't think about the fact that O could have just 1 element. Also the formulation of the sentence in the notes was quite unclear. Thank you!

Promoting the comment to an answer.
Presumably we can assume that $n\ge3$. Therefore either $O$ or $\Omega\setminus O$ has at least two elements. This means that the subgroup $K$ contains a 2-cycle interchanging those two elements, and keeping everything else fixed. Because $K\le M$, the same applies to $M$.
